# Timeout on click event when action is opening a new window

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, window-handles

I'm writing some selenium automation using c# in Visual Studio with NUnit and Chrome browser. In the webpage there is a Yes button which opens a new window.

The webpage states

Do you wish to proceed Yes / No?

Answer [Yes] a new window opens and then another new window within that with a [Print] button

When the [Yes] button is clicked in Selenium the new window opens but the click event does not complete, the code hangs on the click and then throws a timeout error after 60 seconds.
To resolve this i enclosed the click in a try catch to handle the error. However the next section of code then times out after 60 seconds as well.

By complete chance i left this code running on the try-catch in debug and found that if i sleep for 9 minutes (so thats 10 minutes in total including the 60 second click timeout), then the code continues without any further timeouts. If i reduce the sleep time the timeout failure re-occurs.

```
try
{
    //This click works but doesnt complete, and then throws a timeout error after 60 seconds and falls into the catch
    DialogYesBtn.Click();

}
catch
{
    Thread.Sleep(540000); //9  minutes if i drop this to 8 minutes then the next step also times out
}

// this works with the above timeouts - if i dont sleep  in the catch this times out after 60 seconds as well 
SeleniumDriver.Instance.SwitchTo().Window(SeleniumDriver.Instance.WindowHandles.Last());

//unable to find this element using POM
PrintBtn.Click();
```

Any idea what is happening here? I need to click a button in the last window but Selenium cant seem to find them. I also need a efficient solution to the code thats currently been written then waiting 10 minutes for some sort of time out to occur.

I put the following section of debug code before the PrintBtn click to loop through each window to see what elements are available but none are found in any window.

```
//finds 3 windows, the original and the 2 that opened onclick
List<string> windows = SeleniumDriver.Instance.WindowHandles.ToList();
foreach (var handle in windows)
{

    SeleniumDriver.Instance.SwitchTo().Window(handle);

    //none of these elements are found in any window
    var elems1 = SeleniumDriver.Instance.FindElements(By.Id("header"));
    var elems2 = SeleniumDriver.Instance.FindElements(By.Id("button-strip"));
    var elems3 = SeleniumDriver.Instance.FindElements(By.TagName("control-button"));
    var elems4 = SeleniumDriver.Instance.FindElements(By.ClassName("action-button"));

}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the link opened on clicking the webpage doesnt load or blocked in your machine/company ?

Comment: No i dont think so? When i run the debug loop:

_SeleniumDriver.Instance.SwitchTo().Window(handle)_

...the new window clearly comes into focus when it is switched to,

Comment: That's fine. I'm asking if the page loading is completed or the `loading` icon in the tab keep spinning ? If some sites loaded by the page (for eg: facebook widgets or youtube widgets) are blocked due to company policy, the loading will stop only after the timeout.

Comment: Thanks, no i cant see anything to suggest the load hasnt completed, no loading icons and nothing spinning. When the Print button is clicked, the new window(s) close and it returns to the main window and the transaction continues to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Having debugged the javascript further i dont think there is a solution within Selenium. The javascript onclick event for the [Yes] button creates a new window with a [Print] button created by the following js code:

```
var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
printWindow.print();
```

It then hangs on the printWindow.print(); waiting for the print button to be pressed. The [Yes] click event does not complete until this is done. Its not possible to do a Click() on the Print button within the click event for the Yes button using Selenium.